# Auto Add Quote Contact as Primary Opportunity Contact

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to create an apex trigger that automatically adds the Quote Contact as the Primary Opportunity Contact. I am using the code below

```
trigger OpportunityContactRoleTrigger on Quote (after insert, after update) {
    List<OpportunityContactRole> roles = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
    for (Quote q : [SELECT Id, Contact.Id, OpportunityId FROM Quote WHERE Id =: Trigger.new AND OpportunityId != null]) {
        OpportunityContactRole role = new OpportunityContactRole();
        role.ContactId = q.Contact.Id;
        role.OpportunityId = q.OpportunityId;
        role.Role = 'Other';
        roles.add(role);
    }
    insert roles;
}
```

However, when I try to publish this to the active instance I get the following error:

> LeapfrogQuoteController.test_invoke() Class   110 1   Failure Message:
>   "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   OpportunityContactRoleTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
>   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Co...

Comment: Can you complete the end of the error please?  "Required fields are missing: [Co..."

Comment: Check all the required fields for `OpportunityContactRole` in your org

Comment: @brovasi, sadly it does not show anything more, that is the end of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your Quote has a ContactId. I think that's your problem your Contact is null.

```
trigger OpportunityContactRoleTrigger on Quote (after insert, after update) {
    List<OpportunityContactRole> roles = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
    for (Quote q : [SELECT Id, ContactId, OpportunityId FROM Quote WHERE Id =: Trigger.new AND OpportunityId != null 
AND ContactId != null]) {
        OpportunityContactRole role = new OpportunityContactRole();
        role.ContactId = q.ContactId;
        role.OpportunityId = q.OpportunityId;
        role.Role = 'Other';
        roles.add(role);
    }
    insert roles;
}
```

Comment: thanks that seemed to work! Only thing I have noticed is that it doesn't set that contact as the Primary contact, just as a contact.

Comment: try with role.isPrimary = true.

Comment: I just noticed that everytime you edit and save the quote, it re-adds the contact as another contact. Just ended up with the same contact on a quote several times!